# Best way to allow creating custom field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a default table in the database and I would like to allow my user to create their own custom fields. What is the best way of doing this? Are most application out there physically editing the database structure?

Comment: No, few applications modify the database schema. And those that do, probably shouldn't. That's asking for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom field table that simply stores key values. You probably don't want to be editing the table structure.

Comment: Disadvantages of this approach: cannot index custom fields and no way to produce efficient reports/queries.

Comment: @pakito You could always use a key/value store for this table instead of your normal relational database. There's probably a question on SO that asks which one would be best for a situation like this.